# Why would a power surge kill my dishwasher, and another surge bring it back to life?

Tags: electrical, dishwasher

This one is strange.  My house seems to have electrical issues - we used to burn out lots of light bulbs way too frequently, some of the outlets can't be used, and blackouts kill my appliances.  Last year, a blackout killed the compressor of my fridge.

About a week ago, we had a blackout and my dishwasher became unresponsive - no lights turning on, no cycles starting.  I cycled every breaker but nothing fixed the dishwasher, and I had given up.  Yesterday we had another blackout and somehow the dishwasher came right back to life.

Blackouts are actually pretty rare, but we've had a lot of heavy rain recently so I don't think the house is causing them.  However:

1. What are some reasons that my house might be so unprotected that it kills appliances like this?
2. How is it possible that the dishwasher is up and running again?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How long did you leave the breaker off when you tried (before the second blackout and revival)? It's possible that the microprocessor had become locked up somehow, and you didn't it off long enough for all the power to drain away and the processor to reset.

Comment: Perhaps. I only cycled it quickly and the blackout lasted much longer, so that might be it

Comment: I suspect you have a much larger problem. Like a bad connection on one of the feeder cables to your house.  Where are you located?  We ask because electrical systems and voltages are vastly different depending on country.

Comment: When the blackout occurs, are you the only one affected? Do others that are affected have similar issues?

Comment: @Tyson, I'm in southern Ontario, Canada.

Comment: @noybman: I'm not sure. I haven't asked my neighbors about the problem

Comment: If you have a multimeter and are comfortable doing so, please measure HOT to NEUTRAL and HOT to GROUND and tell us the #. Do your incandescent bulbs flicker ever (regularly)

Comment: @noybman: we have 116V between HOT and NEUTRAL and the same between NEUTRAL and GROUND.  I don't recall the bulbs flickering, we're on LED now.  The bulbs just kept burning out

Comment: Sorry, make that 116 between hot and ground

Comment: See if your neighbors have problems. You might want to get an electrician out to at least inspect and check the mains, they will be able to give you an overall assessment of some of the other issues you noted but havent addressed yet. Lastly, after getting input from an electrician, you might need to have the power company replace/fix the drop, see what your neighbors say so you know if it affects everyone nearby